# GDPR - Who Called Me type of situation

Tags: gdpr, phone

I would like to ask how does it work with GDPR and a service like "who called me".

Basically there are no publicly listed phone numbers as these kind of websites are using pretty much every number from 00xx. to 99xx. - so both existing and non existing numbers. And its up to user to find/report particular number.

But once someone wants to flag/comment particular number as spam, the actual number has to be in a database. But no numbers are revealed unless a person search for that number which means he has to know it first anyway.

It is a bit tricky for me to understand whether this falls into GDPR rules or not and any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to run that kind of service, talk to a real lawyer. If not: phone numbers are certainly personal data. Does the operator claim a legitimate purpose to process that without express permission?

Comment: I genuinely do not know: is phone number spoofing a thing in the EU such as it is in the US? I've even gotten spam phone calls from myself in the past (the number that appeared on the caller id was my own (!) phone number.